# jQuery .val() returns empty string

Tags: jquery

It feels like jQuery is messing with me, although it's probably a simple issue. My code get's to the DOM-element that i want to get the value of, but when i add .val() it returns an empty string.

```
$('tr.invoice td[data-attr=Payed] div.true').closest('tr').find('td[data-attr=Expiration]')
Returns this:
[<td data-attr=​"Expiration">​2012-04-22​</td>​,<td data-attr=​"Expiration">​2012-05-21​</td>​,<td data-attr=​"Expiration">​2012-06-18​</td>​]
```

As you can see the DOM-elements has values, but if i add .val() to the JS-string it returns empty strings only (not undefined, empty)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Method `val()` is used for `input` and `select` elements.

You should use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) methods instead.

```
$('tr.invoice td[data-attr=Payed] div.true')
    .closest('tr')
    .find('td[data-attr=Expiration]')
    .each(function() {
        // getting inner HTML
        var html = $(this).html();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

`.val()` is for form elements, not textual values. Use `.text()` intstead.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8V4A/

**EDIT:** Apologies on the bad link.

Comment: not the down-voter but I changed your link description since you said it was a fiddle.

Comment: @BZink: My CMD-C must have missed, apologies, and it's fixed!

Answer (score 3):

`<td>`s don't have values, therefore won't return anything. `.val()` is only used on form elements like `<inputs>` and `<select>` tags. To get the contents of an element, use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead.

The difference between `.html()` and `.text()` is that the former will include the tags in the returned string, while `.text()` will only return the contents of any tags. With this example HTML:

```
<div>
    <strong>
        Hello world
        <span>How're you doing?</span>
    </strong>
</div>
```

`$('div').html()` gives this string (formatted nicely for clarity):

```
<strong>
    Hello world
    <span>How're you doing?</span>
</strong>
```

Whereas `$('div').text()` would give this:

```
Hello worldHow're you doing?
```