# jquery val() will not display value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

### html() should be used for setting content in non-form elements such as div's. ** this question has been answered a few times, which I was unaware of.

I am trying to set a value after retrieving comments from a $.ajax call. When I alert out the values of commentOutput and commentSpan, they are showing the correct data. However, when I try to set the value from those comments in a span, they do not show up, not do they appear in the generated source.

Here is the javascript. You can see the return from the POST in your console. You can also see the value it is grabbing for the span, as I have alerted it onclick.

To invoke this, just click the first picture of the cat, none of the others have comments at this point.

```
var ajaxOptions = {
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'ajax/comments.php',
    data: { id: photoID, action: 'GetComments' },
    success: function(data) {

            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {

                    var commentOutput = '<div><h4>'+data[i].comment_user+' says:</h4>';
                    commentOutput += '<span>'+data[i].comment_msg+'</span>';
                    commentOutput += '</div>';
                    var commentSpan = '#photo' + data[i].photo_id + ' .comments';
                    $(commentSpan).val(commentOutput);
                    $(commentSpan).delay('200').css('display','block');
            }

    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers,

Cody

Comment: You should try to search if solution exist anywhere on SO before posting question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .val() returns empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300043/jquery-val-returns-empty-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `val()` is used for `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements.

You should use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) methods instead.

*NB:* That's the exact copy of [my recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300060/1249581) for almost the same question. Have you tried to find the solution using some searching?

Comment: ... and `<textarea>` ... they get so little love :(

Comment: @Pointy LOL I also forgot about it :) Thanks!

Comment: @Pointy. Actually not just those, what about `<progress>`... The right phrase is form elements.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes i did do three seperate searches on SO, unfortunately i did not find this answer as there are many similar issues that are not quite right.

Answer (score 3):

You want `.html()`, not `.val()`.

```
$(commentSpan).html(commentOutput);
```

Also if your server isn't HTML-escaping the comment data, you should do it in your script:

```
function safe(s) {
  return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/</g, '&lt;');
}

// ...


var commentOutput = '<div><h4>'+ safe(data[i].comment_user) + ' says:</h4>';
commentOutput += '<span>'  + safe(data[i].comment_msg) + '</span>';
```